# Add a comment to an order [API REST]

Tags: magento2, php, orders, api, rest-api

I want to add a comment to a magento order. When i try to do this with postman it works properly:

[image: Postman post]

But when i do this with my php code, the request return an error:

```
//GET TOKEN
$url = '***/rest/V1/integration/admin/token';

$datos_usuario = array("username" => "****", "password" => "*****");

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datos_usuario);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES.UTF-8');
$DateTime = new DateTime();
$fecha = date("Y-m-d")." ".date("H:i:s");

$json = json_decode($result, true);

        $url = '****/rest/V1/orders/430/comments';
    
        $data = [
            "statusHistory" => [
                "comment" => "Pedido entregado al cliente",
                "created_at" => $fecha,
                "parent_id" => "", 
                "is_customer_notified" => 0, 
                "parent_id" => 430,
                "is_customer_notified" => 0,
                "is_visible_on_front" => 1, 
                "status" => "complete"
            ]
        ];

        $data_string = json_encode($data);
        $authorization = "Authorization: Bearer ".$json;

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization ));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        $result2 = curl_exec($curl);
        
        $result = curl_exec($session);
        curl_close($session);
        $json2 = json_decode($result);

        var_dump($json2);
}
```

The error:

```
"message": "% fieldName \ is required." Enter it and try again. "
 "parameters": {
     "fieldName": "statusHistory"
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable/Type issue at your code;

**Changes**

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization ));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
$result2 = curl_exec($curl);

$result = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);
```

**To**

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization ));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
$result2 = curl_exec($curl);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Ohhhhhhh thank you so much!!!!! I was going crazy. I'm so stupid ... hahahaha Thanks again